# Can a surface of general type with $p_g=q=0$ be a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose that canonical class $K_S$ is ample i.e. $S$ is of general type, irregularity and geometric genus vanish $q(S)=p_g(S)=0$.

Can such surface be a fibration i.e. is there a surjective map $S \to C$, where $C$ is a smooth projective curve?

Comment: Observation: you've assumed that $S$ admits no holomorphic $1$-forms. Since a $1$-form on $C$ induces one on $S$ by pullback, this implies that $C \cong \mathbb P^1$. I don't know if this helps.